# Delphi AV when using TStringList in a custom class

Tags: class, delphi

In Delphi Rio, I have created a class whose purpose is to read a record from a database.  This record is purely read only, and after reading, I need to derive some additional properties.  My problem has to do with a Stringlist I am wanting to use in my class definition.  I have a private class member called fVENDORS_TO_COLORCODE.  This is a comma separated string. I am wanting to make a property that is a TStringlist.  I am using TStringList.CommaToText to load my value into the Tstringlist. I do this in the Create Constructor.  The issue I am having is that while the StringList is valid in the constructor, it is nil outside of the constructor, and I don't know what I am doing wrong.  Here is the relevant portions of code.

```
type
  TProfileDef = class(TObject)
  private
    fNAME: String;   
    fVENDORS_TO_COLORCODE: String;  // incoming comma separated string. Example string:  Microsoft,IBM
    fVENDORS_TO_COLORCODE_SL : TStringList;
    ..

  public  
    constructor Create(ProfileName: String); 
    destructor Destroy; override;   
  published   
    property NAME: String read fNAME;  
    property VENDORS_TO_COLORCODE: String read fVENDORS_TO_COLORCODE;
    property VENDORS_TO_COLORCODE_SL : TStringList read fVENDORS_TO_COLORCODE_SL;  
    ..
  end;

implementation

destructor TProfileDef.Destroy;
begin
inherited;
  fVENDORS_TO_COLORCODE_SL.Free;
end;


constructor TProfileDef.Create(ProfileName: String);
var
  fVENDORS_SL: TStringList;
  fVENDORS_TO_COLORCODE_SL: TStringList;
  TempVendorList : String;

begin
inherited Create;
fName := ProfileName;

.. [Find my record based on ProfileName, and load the DB columns into the private variables]..

    // Load the Color Code String into a StringList;
    fVENDORS_TO_COLORCODE_SL := TStringList.Create;   
    fVENDORS_TO_COLORCODE_SL.CommaToText :=  fVENDORS_TO_COLORCODE; 
end;
```

Within the Constructor, the fVENDORS_TO_COLORCODE_SL stringlist is created, and data is added...
The issue is when I try to use it...

```
var
TestClass: TProfileDef;
begin
TestClass := TProfileDef.Create('Sample Profile');
// TestClass.Name is valid
// TestClass.VENDORS_TO_COLORCODE_SL is nil, and trying to access gives AV
```

Somehow I am defining this wrong, but I can't determine what it is is, in order to correct it.

Comment: In the constructor, you have local variables that hide the class members.

Comment: Yeah, remove those local variables. Why did you add them at all? Seems like your destructor should destroy both string lists also, but we can't see enough code to be sure.

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple,,,  submit as answer and I will accept;  The destructor does destroy both stringlists BTW.  Thanks

Comment: No. This destructor only destroys one. Have a look above.

Comment: @@David, taken care of.... thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class has a private field

```
fVENDORS_TO_COLORCODE_SL: TStringList;
```

Your constructor should create a `TStringList` object and have this variable point to it. I assume that is your intention, at least. However, your constructor *has a local variable with the same name*, `fVENDORS_TO_COLORCODE_SL`, so the line

```
fVENDORS_TO_COLORCODE_SL := TStringList.Create;
```

indeed creates a `TStringList` object, but the pointer is saved *to this local variable*, and the class's field with the same name remains `nil`.

Solution: Remove the declaration of the local variable in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Load the Color Code String into a StringList;
fVENDORS_TO_COLORCODE_SL := TStringList.Create;
```

This line here in the constructor is the problem. You have two variables named `fVENDORS_TO_COLORCODE_SL`. One is a private member of the class declared in the `private` section of th class declaration, the other is a local variable declared in the `var` section of the constructor.
Guess which one takes precedence. That's right, the local variable in the constructor. That line initialized the local variable named `fVENDORS_TO_COLORCODE_SL`, the private class member with the same name is still `nil`. 
As a general rule I preface local variables in a method with an l and only preface class members with an f to avoid just this sort of problem.
Rename your local variables in the constructor like so:

```
constructor TProfileDef.Create(ProfileName: String);
var
  lVENDORS_SL: TStringList;
  lVENDORS_TO_COLORCODE_SL: TStringList;
  lTempVendorList : String;
begin
```

Then update your code and rebuild. Things should start to become obvious pretty quickly.